# haxe: Indirect property referencing

Tags: flash, haxe

I might be missing something obvious, but how do I reference a property indirectly? E.g in javascript it would be:

```
 if(propName in obj) return obj[propName];
```

How to say the same in haxe? The object in question is `Dynamic<String>`, `flash.display.LoaderInfo.parameters` to be specific.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(Reflect.hasField(obj, propName)) return Reflect.field(obj, propName);
```

Althought it seems more code, the generated output is basically the same.